# Does JavaScript 'Set' work for HTMLStyleElement objects?

Tags: javascript, css, set

In my website there are some duplicated `<Style>` elements in DOM. I am trying to use a Set in JavaScript to do some de-duplication for these  elements. The code to generate non-dup elements is something like:

```
const CSSCache = new Set<HTMLStyleElement>();
const styles = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
for (let i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
   CSSCache.add(styles[i] as HTMLStyleElement);
}
```

I am wondering if the JavaScript Set able to unique-fy these HTMLStyleElement objects.

Also, some of these  elelment doesn't have any content, e.g. `<style></style>` but they have rules in element.sheet.cssRules inserted with insertRule (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule). I am wondering if Set works for these types of Style as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Set contains values that are unique via the `Object.is` algorithm, which is nearly the same as how `===` works.

Separate `<style>` objects on the page, regardless of content are not `===`, so you'll get a Set with all `<style>`s on the page with your current code.

The same is true for any HTMLElement, and even true for plain objects.

```js
const set = new Set();
const obj1 = {};
const obj2 = {};
set.add(obj1);
set.add(obj2);
console.log(set.size);
```

If you want to de-duplicate, you will have to go another route - such as iterating through the rules of each style.